# accumulate over tuple of values

Tags: c++, c++11

I am playing with tuples and templates.  I know if practice you would use boost::fusion (I think) to do this kind of thing.  I am trying to implement the equivalent of std::accumulate over a tuple.

Below is the code that I have.  As near as I can tell the compile error is caused by it trying to use the 4 template parameter version when I intended it to use to the 3 template parameter version to finish recursing.  This would imply that I missed something with the function overload resolution.

I had thought that since both functions could be matched that it would pick the 3 template parameter version as being the better match since the last parameter type is explicitly stated.  I still get the same behavior if I add std::tuple_size as an additional template parameter to both versions of tuple_accumulate_helper.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t I>
struct int_{};

template <typename T, typename OutT, typename OpT, std::size_t IndexI>
auto tuple_accumulate_helper(T tuple, OutT init, OpT op, int_<IndexI>) -> decltype(tuple_accumulate_helper(tuple, op(init, std::get<IndexI>(tuple)), op, int_<IndexI + 1>()))
{
   return tuple_accumulate_helper(tuple, op(init, std::get<IndexI>(tuple)), op, int_<IndexI + 1>());
}

template <typename T, typename OutT, typename OpT>
auto tuple_accumulate_helper(T tuple, OutT init, OpT op, int_<std::tuple_size<T>::value>) -> decltype(init)
{
   return init;
}

template <typename T, typename OutT, typename OpT>
auto tuple_accumulate(T tuple, OutT init, OpT op) -> decltype(tuple_accumulate_helper(tuple, init, op, int_<0>()))
{
   return tuple_accumulate_helper(tuple, init, op, int_<0>());
}

struct functor
{
   template <typename T1, typename T2>
   auto operator()(T1 t1, T2 t2) -> decltype(t1 + t2)
   {
      return t1 + t2;
   }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
   auto val = tuple_accumulate(std::make_tuple(5, 3.2, 7, 6.4f), 0, functor());
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: VS is a compliance laggard. Use an online compiler such as http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ or http://ideone.com to get opinions from several more up-to-date compiler installations. According to Clang, you have an index overflow error, using index = 4 into a tuple of size 4. What did VC say?

Comment: Your code looks fine except int_<std::tuple_size<T>::value> should be int_<std::tuple_size<T>::value–1>. It didn't compile on gcc4.8.1. it works on msvc2013 v120.

Comment: Running it through clang it appears that when I was expecting it to select the overload with 3 template parameters it is selecting the overload with 4 template parameters and then is failing to instantiate std::get for one past the end of the tuple.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you're interested, but if you can use a little boost, you can have this "out of the box":

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>

using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto t = std::make_tuple(5, 3.2, 7, 6.4f); 

    std::cout << boost::fusion::accumulate(t, 0, arg1 + arg2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::fusion::accumulate(t, 1, arg1 * arg2) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
21.6
716.8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the compiler to match a template specialization which depends on a nested type, `std::tuple_size<T>::value` in your example, [ [Partial specialization with type nested in a templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114185/partial-specialization-with-type-nested-in-a-templated-class) ] so you have to find alternative ways to let the compiler know when the recursion ends.

In the code snippet below I provide an alternative. I by no means claim my solution is the "best" by any measure, but I believe it may be helpful in showing you how to approach this problem:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>


//deduces the type resulted from the folding of a sequence from left to right
//avoids the decltype nonsense
template <typename T, typename OpT>
class result_of_acumulate;

template <typename... ArgsT, typename OpT>
class result_of_acumulate<std::tuple<ArgsT...>, OpT>
{
private:
    template <typename... ArgsHeadT>
    struct result_of_acumulate_helper;

    template <typename ArgsHeadT>
    struct result_of_acumulate_helper<ArgsHeadT>
    {
        typedef ArgsHeadT type;
    };

    template <typename ArgsHead1T, typename ArgsHead2T>
    struct result_of_acumulate_helper<ArgsHead1T, ArgsHead2T>
    {
        typedef typename std::result_of<OpT(ArgsHead1T, ArgsHead2T)>::type type;
    };

    template <typename ArgsHead1T, typename ArgsHead2T, typename... ArgsTailT>
    struct result_of_acumulate_helper<ArgsHead1T, ArgsHead2T, ArgsTailT...>
    {
        typedef typename result_of_acumulate_helper<typename std::result_of<OpT(ArgsHead1T, ArgsHead2T)>::type, ArgsTailT...>::type type;
    };

public:
    typedef typename result_of_acumulate_helper<ArgsT...>::type type;
};

template <std::size_t IndexI, typename T, typename OutT, typename OpT>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<(IndexI == std::tuple_size<T>::value), OutT>::type
tuple_accumulate_helper(T const& /*tuple*/, OutT const& init, OpT /*op*/)
{
    return init;
}

template <std::size_t IndexI, typename T, typename OutT, typename OpT>
constexpr typename std::enable_if
<
    (IndexI < std::tuple_size<T>::value),
    typename result_of_acumulate<T, OpT>::type
>::type
tuple_accumulate_helper(T const& tuple, OutT const init, OpT op)
{
    return tuple_accumulate_helper<IndexI + 1>(tuple, op(init, std::get<IndexI>(tuple)), op);
}

template <typename T, typename OutT, typename OpT>
auto tuple_accumulate(T const& tuple, OutT const& init, OpT op)
    -> decltype(tuple_accumulate_helper<0>(tuple, init, op))
{
    return tuple_accumulate_helper<0>(tuple, init, op);
}

struct functor
{
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    auto operator()(T1 t1, T2 t2)
        -> decltype(t1 + t2)
    {
        return t1 + t2;
    }
};

int main(int /*argc*/, const char* /*argv*/[])
{
    auto val = tuple_accumulate(std::make_tuple(5, 3.2, 7U, 6.4f), 0L, functor());
    std::cout << val << std::endl; //should output 21.6
    return 0;
}
```

Successfully compiled and tested using gcc (GCC) 4.8.1 20130725 (prerelease) on an Archlinux x64 box.

Comment: +1 because it works, while compiling in literally 1/10th of the time my boost example takes :/

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion: because std::tuples can carry non numerical types, you should make your functor aware of this possibility and warn you at compile time.

Here is a suggestion that uses SFINAE

```
struct functor
{
   template <typename T1, typename T2,
   typename std::enable_if< std::is_arithmetic<T1>::value == true && 
   std::is_arithmetic<T2>::value == true , bool>::type = false >
   auto operator()(T1 t1, T2 t2) -> decltype(t1 + t2)
   {
      return t1 + t2;
   }
};
```

type traits are very important to restrict the types you want to accept in your template function/class/functor

Update 1: another suggestion using static_assert (which will give clear error messages when trigger)

```
struct functor
{
   template <typename T1, typename T2 >
   auto operator()(T1 t1, T2 t2) -> decltype(t1 + t2)
   {
      static_assert( std::is_arithmetic<T1>::value == true && 
   std::is_arithmetic<T2>::value == true )
      return t1 + t2;
   }
};
```