# boost::fusion::accumulate simple example

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14, fusion

I have what I hope is a simple example, with a simple question someone can help clear up for me :). It's based on this other question:
[accumulate over tuple of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735938/accumulate-over-tuple-of-values)

What I have is a structure, with a `std::tuple<std::string>` member. During the structure's constructor, I store the data after performing some algorithms controlled by another type. Not related to my question, just explaining the code below.

What I need help with (sorry, new to boost metaprogramming!) is my `toString()` method that invokes `boost::fusion::accumulate` on the tuple I have. When I call `boost::fusion::accumulate`, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be calling it!
The call to `boost::fusion::accumulate` should be dictated by the `AlgorithmT` parameter.

I have the following code more or less:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>

template<typename AlgorithmT, typename ...T>
struct Trait
{
  using A = AlgorithmT;

  size_t hash_value_;
  std::tuple<std::string> value_;

  Trait(T... data) :
    hash_value_(A::Hash(data...)),
    value_(A::Transform(data...)) {}
  size_t hash() const { return this->hash_value_; }

  std::string toString() const
  {
    using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;
    // This example compiles, but it effectively does nothing. result is always empty.
    std::string const result = boost::fusion::accumulate(this->value_, std::string{}, arg1);

    // This next line doesn't compile, but I think it's what I want.
    std::string const result = boost::fusion::accumulate(this->value_, std::string{}, &A::ToString(arg1));
    return result;
  }
};

struct IdentityAlgorithms
{
  static constexpr size_t (*Hash)(std::string const&) = &boost::hash_value;
  static constexpr auto Transform = &identity_transform<std::string>;

  static std::string ToString(std::string value) {
    std::cerr << "ToString invoked! value: '" << value << "'" << std::endl;
    return "\"" + value + "\""; }
};
```

Could someone look at how I am using `boost::fusion::accumulate`, and maybe point out how I can get the compiler to deduce the type. I'm assuming the compiler can't deduce the right type for a good reason, I'm just not sure what that is. The error messages GCC4.9 is spitting out at me is:

> required from here
>   `/local/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Boost/Boost-3.0.3932.1/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/include/boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/detail/preprocessed/fold.hpp`:`111`:`39`:
>   error: too many arguments to function
>                        `fusion::deref(it0));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>

template<typename AlgorithmT, typename ...T>
struct Trait
{
    using A = AlgorithmT;

    size_t hash_value_;
    std::tuple<std::string> value_;

    Trait(T... data) :
        hash_value_(A::Hash(data...)),
        value_(A::Transform(data...)) {}
    size_t hash() const { return this->hash_value_; }

    std::string toString() const
    {
        using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;

        const std::string result = boost::fusion::accumulate(this->value_, std::string{} /* initila state */, A());
        return result;
    }
};

struct IdentityAlgorithms
{
    typedef std::string result_type;

    static constexpr size_t (*Hash)(std::string const&) = &boost::hash_value;
    static constexpr auto Transform = &identity_transform<std::string>;

    std::string operator()(const std::string& str, const std::string &value) const
                                          //  ^ state                 ^ element of squence
    {
        std::cerr << "ToString invoked! value: '" << value << "'" << std::endl;
        return "\"" + value + "\"";
    }
};
```

Operation `static std::string ToString(std::string value)` makes no sense in this case. You have to define `operator()`.

Comment: What did you do? Can you explain it.

Comment: I needed to define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE to get this to work, thanks!